# Echo PDO query for debugging purposes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For debugging purposes, how do I echo the query generated by PDO so I can see what it is about the execute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use: [$PDOStatement->queryString](http://php.net/manual/class.pdostatement.php#pdostatement.props.querystring)

Example code:

```
$usedParams = array(
  ':id' => 1
);

echo str_replace(
  array_keys($usedParams), $usedParams, $stmt->queryString
);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, that gives me `select * from table1 where id = :id`.  I want to see the query which is about to be run with the correct value, i.e. `select * from table1 where id = 1` or whatever the `:id` contains

Comment: @oshirowanen That `queryString` property is the only help you'll get from pdo in this regards. If you want the final query, you'll have to inject the used parameters into the `queryString` yourself.

Comment: @oshirowanen I added an example of how this could be done. Note that the final string will probably not be a correct query, but as this is just for debugging, I think it's enough. :)